# Investigate whole branch history, rather then particular file (alternative to SourceTree History option)

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Navigating to `VCS` --> `Git` --> `Show History` would usually show the history of the current file. But I wonder if there is a way to navigate the whole branch in a tree like model that's is available for example in SourceTree:[image: w]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the Log tab in the Version Control tool window, that shows the entire history of the project with the graph.

To see a specific branch, just filter it using the Branch filter.

[image]

Comment: The full path VCS --> Browse VCS Repository --> Show Git Repository Log

Comment: VCS --> Browse VCS Repository --> Show Git Repository Log allows to view you Log of an arbitrary repository. Log of the repository that is currently registered in the project is shown in the Log tab by default. Just open Version Control toolwindow to see it. BTW, you can assign a shortcut to open it - search for Show VCS Log in Settings - Keymap